# how to merge string based on a value criteria

Tags: r

I have a data like the following

```
df<-structure(list(position = structure(c(6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
1L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15", 
"2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16", "3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17", 
"4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18", "TP<AMB88", "TP<AMT55", 
"TP<ELANE", "TP<RACK1"), class = "factor"), col = structure(c(15L, 
6L, 3L, 11L, 5L, 14L, 9L, 18L, 16L, 8L, 13L, 4L, 2L, 17L, 7L, 
12L, 1L, 10L), .Label = c("EQMTLRGTLKGHNGW", "GRRLACLFLACVLPA", 
"GSLSNYALLQLTLTA", "LGRRLACLFLACVLP", "LSNYALLQLTLTAFL", "MGSLSNYALLQLTLT", 
"MTEQMTLRGTLKGHN", "MTLGRRLACLFLACV", "MVKETTYYDVLGVKP", "QMTLRGTLKGHNGWV", 
"SLSNYALLQLTLTAF", "TEQMTLRGTLKGHNG", "TLGRRLACLFLACVL", "TP<AMB88", 
"TP<AMT55", "TP<ELANE", "TP<RACK1", "VKETTYYDVLGVKPN"), class = "factor"), 
    newcol = structure(c(13L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 11L, 12L, 9L, 9L, 14L, 
    7L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 15L, 1L, 8L, 2L, 10L), .Label = c("1.189898095", 
    "1.323231429", "1.732914564", "1.789898095", "1.866247897", 
    "2.732914564", "2.973557262", "3.139572262", "3.189898095", 
    "3.323231429", "3.87645", "TP<AMB88", "TP<AMT55", "TP<ELANE", 
    "TP<RACK1"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-18L))
```

I want merge the strings in each section if they meet a criteria so if the `newcol` is lower than 2 then merge them if they are in one section

for example , we look at column `col` and `TP<AMP55` is one section

so we look at the column `newcol` and we see two of them has values less than 2

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15 MGSLSNYALLQLTLT      1.866247897
2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16    GSLSNYALLQLTLTA  1.732914564
```

Then I want to merge these two based on the first column , it says 1,2,3 .... in the first row and 2,3,4, ... so it can become like this

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16  MGSLSNYALLQLTLTA
```

So I want an output like this

```
out<- structure(list(position = structure(c(6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
1L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15", 
"2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16", "3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17", 
"4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18", "TP<AMB88", "TP<AMT55", 
"TP<ELANE", "TP<RACK1"), class = "factor"), col = structure(c(15L, 
6L, 3L, 11L, 5L, 14L, 9L, 18L, 16L, 8L, 13L, 4L, 2L, 17L, 7L, 
12L, 1L, 10L), .Label = c("EQMTLRGTLKGHNGW", "GRRLACLFLACVLPA", 
"GSLSNYALLQLTLTA", "LGRRLACLFLACVLP", "LSNYALLQLTLTAFL", "MGSLSNYALLQLTLT", 
"MTEQMTLRGTLKGHN", "MTLGRRLACLFLACV", "MVKETTYYDVLGVKP", "QMTLRGTLKGHNGWV", 
"SLSNYALLQLTLTAF", "TEQMTLRGTLKGHNG", "TLGRRLACLFLACVL", "TP<AMB88", 
"TP<AMT55", "TP<ELANE", "TP<RACK1", "VKETTYYDVLGVKPN"), class = "factor"), 
    newcol = structure(c(13L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 11L, 12L, 9L, 9L, 14L, 
    7L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 15L, 1L, 8L, 2L, 10L), .Label = c("1.189898095", 
    "1.323231429", "1.732914564", "1.789898095", "1.866247897", 
    "2.732914564", "2.973557262", "3.139572262", "3.189898095", 
    "3.323231429", "3.87645", "TP<AMB88", "TP<AMT55", "TP<ELANE", 
    "TP<RACK1"), class = "factor"), Newposition = structure(c(1L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16", 
    "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17", "2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18"
    ), class = "factor"), newcol2 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", 
    "MGSLSNYALLQLTLTA", "MTEQMTLRGTLKGHNGW", "TLGRRLACLFLACVLPA"
    ), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-18L))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this, which extracts the final integers/letters and uses `dplyr::accumulate` to combine them before adding them to the first row of each section where `as.double(newcol) < 2`. To match the right accumulated ending to the first <2 in each section I first group by section and <2, then I use `dplyr::lead` to shift everything up:

```r
df %>% 
    mutate_all(as.character) %>% 
    mutate(sect = col == newcol,
           group = cumsum(sect),
           less_2 = replace_na(as.double(newcol) < 2, F)
           ) %>% 
    group_by(group, sect) %>% 
    mutate(Newposition = str_extract(position, "\\d+$") %>%
               accumulate(c) %>%
               map_chr(str_c, collapse = ","),
           newcol2 = str_extract(col, ".$") %>%
               accumulate(c) %>%
               map_chr(str_c, collapse = "")
           ) %>% 
    group_by(less_2, add = T) %>% 
    mutate(Newposition = lead(Newposition) %>% str_replace("^\\d+", position),
           Newposition = ifelse(less_2, Newposition, "") %>% replace_na(""),
           newcol2 = lead(newcol2) %>% str_replace("^.", col),
           newcol2 = ifelse(less_2, newcol2, "") %>% replace_na("")
           ) %>% 
    ungroup %>% 
    select(-(sect:less_2))
```

The code should yield the following data frame. It will also throw a warning, but it doesn't affect the output:

```
                                 position             col      newcol           newcol2                                Newposition
1                                TP<AMT55        TP<AMT55    TP<AMT55                                                             
2     1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15 MGSLSNYALLQLTLT 1.866247897  MGSLSNYALLQLTLTA     1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16
3    2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16 GSLSNYALLQLTLTA 1.732914564                                                             
4   3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17 SLSNYALLQLTLTAF 2.732914564                                                             
5  4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18 LSNYALLQLTLTAFL     3.87645                                                             
6                                TP<AMB88        TP<AMB88    TP<AMB88                                                             
7     1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15 MVKETTYYDVLGVKP 3.189898095                                                             
8    2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16 VKETTYYDVLGVKPN 3.189898095                                                             
9                                TP<ELANE        TP<ELANE    TP<ELANE                                                             
10    1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15 MTLGRRLACLFLACV 2.973557262                                                             
11   2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16 TLGRRLACLFLACVL 1.732914564 TLGRRLACLFLACVLPA 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18
12  3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17 LGRRLACLFLACVLP 2.732914564                                                             
13 4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18 GRRLACLFLACVLPA 1.789898095                                                             
14                               TP<RACK1        TP<RACK1    TP<RACK1                                                             
15    1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15 MTEQMTLRGTLKGHN 1.189898095 MTEQMTLRGTLKGHNGW  1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17
16   2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16 TEQMTLRGTLKGHNG 3.139572262                                                             
17  3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17 EQMTLRGTLKGHNGW 1.323231429                                                             
18 4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18 QMTLRGTLKGHNGWV 3.323231429
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all your data is not tidy.

### Step 1:

Get rid of the multiple data types in a column and move 'section' to a new column.

```
require(tidyverse)
require(zoo)

dfsection <- df %>% tbl_df() %>%
  mutate(section = if_else(grepl("[A-Z]",position),
                           as.character(position),
                           as.character(NA))) %>%
  mutate(section = na.locf(section)) 

newdf <- dfsection %>%
  filter(!grepl("[A-Z]",position))%>%
  mutate_if(is.factor,as.character) %>%
  mutate(newcol = as.numeric(newcol))
```

`newdf` gives

```
# A tibble: 14 x 4
   position                               col             newcol section 
   <chr>                                  <chr>            <dbl> <chr>   
 1 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15    MGSLSNYALLQLTLT   1.87 TP<AMT55
 2 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16   GSLSNYALLQLTLTA   1.73 TP<AMT55
 3 3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17  SLSNYALLQLTLTAF   2.73 TP<AMT55
 4 4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18 LSNYALLQLTLTAFL   3.88 TP<AMT55
 5 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15    MVKETTYYDVLGVKP   3.19 TP<AMB88
 6 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16   VKETTYYDVLGVKPN   3.19 TP<AMB88
 7 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15    MTLGRRLACLFLACV   2.97 TP<ELANE
 8 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16   TLGRRLACLFLACVL   1.73 TP<ELANE
 9 3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17  LGRRLACLFLACVLP   2.73 TP<ELANE
10 4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18 GRRLACLFLACVLPA   1.79 TP<ELANE
11 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15    MTEQMTLRGTLKGHN   1.19 TP<RACK1
12 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16   TEQMTLRGTLKGHNG   3.14 TP<RACK1
13 3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17  EQMTLRGTLKGHNGW   1.32 TP<RACK1
14 4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18 QMTLRGTLKGHNGWV   3.32 TP<RACK1
```

### Step 2:

Make a function to normalise the data to a point where each position and letter is a row in the `dataframe`

```
splitstring <- function(pos,letters){
  posvec <- as.numeric(str_split(pos,",")[[1]])
  data.frame(pos = posvec,
             letter = str_sub(letters,seq_along(posvec),seq_along(posvec)),
             stringsAsFactors = F)
}

#example
splitstring(newdf[2,'position'],newdf[2,'col'])
```

gives

```
   pos letter
1    2      G
2    3      S
3    4      L
4    5      S
5    6      N
6    7      Y
7    8      A
8    9      L
9   10      L
10  11      Q
11  12      L
12  13      T
13  14      L
14  15      T
15  16      A
```

### step 3:

Apply this function `splitstring` on your `dataframe`.

```
normdf <- newdf %>%
  mutate(newdat = map2(position,col,splitstring)) %>% 
  select(section,newdat,newcol) %>%
  unnest()
```

`normdf` gives:

```
# A tibble: 210 x 4
   section  newcol   pos letter
   <chr>     <dbl> <dbl> <chr> 
 1 TP<AMT55   1.87     1 M     
 2 TP<AMT55   1.87     2 G     
 3 TP<AMT55   1.87     3 S     
 4 TP<AMT55   1.87     4 L     
 5 TP<AMT55   1.87     5 S     
 6 TP<AMT55   1.87     6 N     
 7 TP<AMT55   1.87     7 Y     
 8 TP<AMT55   1.87     8 A     
 9 TP<AMT55   1.87     9 L     
10 TP<AMT55   1.87    10 L     
# ... with 200 more rows
```

### step 4:

Finally filter letters associated with a `newcol` value < 2. Find out the distinct `letter` and `position` combinations per section.
Combine in one string.

```
result <- normdf %>%
  filter(newcol < 2) %>%
  select(-newcol) %>%
  distinct() %>%
  group_by(section) %>%
  summarise(Newposition = paste(pos, collapse = ","),
            newcol2 = paste(letter, collapse = ""))
```

`result` gives

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  section  Newposition                                newcol2          
  <chr>    <chr>                                      <chr>            
1 TP<AMT55 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16     MGSLSNYALLQLTLTA 
2 TP<ELANE 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18 TLGRRLACLFLACVLPA
3 TP<RACK1 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17  MTEQMTLRGTLKGHNGW
```

### Step 5:

Link back to untidy data

```
dfsection %>% mutate(link = str_sub(position,1,1)) %>%
  left_join(result %>% mutate(link = str_sub(Newposition,1,1)) %>%
              select(link,section,Newposition,newcol2), by = c('section','link')) %>%
  select(-link,-section) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(Newposition,newcol2),coalesce,'') %>%
  as.data.frame
```

gives:

```
                                 position             col      newcol                                Newposition
1                                TP<AMT55        TP<AMT55    TP<AMT55                                           
2     1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15 MGSLSNYALLQLTLT 1.866247897     1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16
3    2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16 GSLSNYALLQLTLTA 1.732914564                                           
4   3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17 SLSNYALLQLTLTAF 2.732914564                                           
5  4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18 LSNYALLQLTLTAFL     3.87645                                           
6                                TP<AMB88        TP<AMB88    TP<AMB88                                           
7     1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15 MVKETTYYDVLGVKP 3.189898095                                           
8    2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16 VKETTYYDVLGVKPN 3.189898095                                           
9                                TP<ELANE        TP<ELANE    TP<ELANE                                           
10    1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15 MTLGRRLACLFLACV 2.973557262                                           
11   2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16 TLGRRLACLFLACVL 1.732914564 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18
12  3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17 LGRRLACLFLACVLP 2.732914564                                           
13 4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18 GRRLACLFLACVLPA 1.789898095                                           
14                               TP<RACK1        TP<RACK1    TP<RACK1                                           
15    1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15 MTEQMTLRGTLKGHN 1.189898095  1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17
16   2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16 TEQMTLRGTLKGHNG 3.139572262                                           
17  3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17 EQMTLRGTLKGHNGW 1.323231429                                           
18 4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18 QMTLRGTLKGHNGWV 3.323231429                                           
             newcol2
1                   
2   MGSLSNYALLQLTLTA
3                   
4                   
5                   
6                   
7                   
8                   
9                   
10                  
11 TLGRRLACLFLACVLPA
12                  
13                  
14                  
15 MTEQMTLRGTLKGHNGW
16                  
17                  
18
```

Comment: thanks but I am looking for the output structure I mentioned above

Comment: I understand that my solution did not give your expected result. I am not sure why you want to work with such a data structure. Please consider a more `tidy` structure (i.e. `newdf`), since in the long run it is easier to work with. Anyway, I've added an extra step to my answer to link the result back to your original data (`df`)